# How to get only one item of same ID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, name product:

```
ProductId    ProductName    CategoryId
   1            Tshirt        1
   2            Jeans         1
   3            Tops          2
   4            Lipstick      2
```

I want output something like this:

```
ProductId    ProductName   CategoryId
 1             Tshirt            1
 3              Tops             2
```

This means only one item for each category. Is it possible to do so using SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of RowNumber() function, but the way I have used it it will pick a random first Product for each CategoryID.

If you want to have more control over what ProductName should be picked use a proper `ORDER BY ColumnName` instead of `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`

```
SELECT ProductId    
      ,ProductName
      ,CategoryId
FROM (
      SELECT *
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
      FROM TableName 
     ) A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: It seems you are faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Use windowing function:

```
WITH AdditionalNumbering AS
(
    SELECT ProductId, ProductName, CategoryID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY ProductID) RowNumber
)
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, CategoryID
FROM AdditionalNumbering
WHERE RowNumber=1
```